# Trying to understand why a "Type Annotations Needed" Rust compiler error is not produced on same line where the type is unspecified

Tags: rust

Consider the following snippet:

```
let maybe_kafka_config = serde_json::from_str(file_contents_as_string.as_str());
let kafka_config = maybe_kafka_config.unwrap();
```

The Rust compiler produces an error relating to the second line, however I would have expected the error to be related to the first line.

- `serde_json::from_str` doesn't have any type information to allow `rustc` to deduce the type of `maybe_kafka_config`. I would have expected to see an error or compiler warning relating to this line.

Instead I see the following:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> apollo/src/main.rs:31:17
   |
31 |             let kafka_config = maybe_kafka_config.unwrap();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: consider giving `kafka_config` an explicit type
   |
31 |             let kafka_config: /* Type */ = maybe_kafka_config.unwrap();
   |                             ++++++++++++
```

Which is an error relating to the second line, not the first.

**Pre-emptive: I know how to fix it. There are two ways. This is not the point of this question.**

- Turbofish
- Specifying the type as `Return<KafkaConfig, _>` (or something more specific for the error part)

```
// Turbofish
serde_json::from_str::<KafkaConfig>

// Using `Return<>`
let maybe_kafka_config: Return<KafkaConfig, _>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Rust compiler tries to defer type inferrence for as long as possible, thus you get the error at the piece of code where it's first absolutely needed.

It's fine to work with "something that implements `Deserialize`" up to the point where you absolutely need it.

That often helps avoid having to annotate at all, for example if you call a function that expects a type:

```rust
fn takes_kafka_config(_: KafkaConfig) {}
fn main() {
    let maybe_kafka_config = serde_json::from_str("{}");
    let kafka_config = maybe_kafka_config.unwrap();
    takes_kafka_config(kafka_config);
}
```

If the compiler threw an error in the first line already it would be for nothing since ultimately it can figure the type out.

Comment: Thanks. In your experience, does this ever cause situations where it becomes difficult to track down the origin of a compiler error? For example, if the type information is "needed" in a separate function or file to where it was originally "created"?

Comment: Not really, function signatures always have to be specified, ie this doesn't propagate across function boundaries.